# Liferay6 /c/portal/fckeditor or documentlibrary: get urls without timestamp param

Tags: liferay

When selecting in web contents an image from the Documentlibrary, or from the filemanager in WYSIWYG editor, the url gets always a timestamp param appended like this:

```
... _15_selectDocumentLibrary('/documents/123/456/test.jpg/3bf320b5-45b5-4bb8-a85c-7dcbdad976c9?t=1380280666000', '3bf320b5-45b5-4bb8-a85c-7dcbdad976c9', 'test\x2ejpg', '1.0');
```

is there a portal property to switch this behavior off?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such a parameter. Without looking at the actual code or HTTP headers, I expect these documents to be cacheable for a long time, and the timestamp denotes the timestamp of last modification (not the current time). This is a neat trick to utilize less bandwidth while still making the latest available document available, without the cost of low timeouts for caching.

If it's just for your own aesthetic sense, you should look elsewhere. The URLs are (typically) not customer facing and you gain quite a bit from them.

Comment: actually the parameter prevents the document from being cached by our frontend cache (Varnish), were no dynamic urls with any GET-Parameter will be cached. So everyone of this urls strike trough the cache to our Liferay-Backends.

Comment: iirc this is per design, as you might not want users to see cached/old versions of updated or deleted documents that could lead to confusion. I thinks there's intent on implementing some kind of configurable policy for this, but not sure what's the current state of this. Creating a feature request for this and getting it voted should help ;)